# Efficiently finding a specific object in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a recursive algorithm that goes through and finds all the sub-words in a word (algorithm below). The problem with my algorithm is that it spams core data with fetch requests, and this makes it run very slowly.

Is there a better way to do this?, or am I stuck with the longer times.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)subwordPermutations:(NSMutableArray *)permutationArray subWord:  (NSMutableString *) subWord {

    if ([subWord length] == 1)
        return permutationArray;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Word"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"alphaSortedWord == %@", subWord];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    JGTAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    NSError *error;
    [permutationArray addObjectsFromArray:[managedObjectContext   executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]];

    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

    for (int i = 0; i < [subWord length]; i++) {

        NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", subWord];
        [temp deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];

        permutationArray = [self subwordPermutations:permutationArray subWord:temp];
    }

   return permutationArray;
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the object in core data has two string properties, the word and the alphabetically sorted word.

Comment: What have you done to check you aren't repeatedly calling `subwordPermutations:` with the same `subWord`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you (recursively) create substrings of a given string, and for each substring
execute a fetch request to check if that string is in the database.

To speed up a single fetch request, you could try to make the "alphaSortedWord" attribute
*Indexed* in the Core Data model inspector.

You should definitely get a performance improvement by working in batches: 
Collect subword candidates in an array first (maybe 100, you have to find out the optimal batch size), and then execute a fetch request with the predicate

```
NSArray *candidates = ...; // array of subword candidates
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"alphaSortedWord IN %@", candidates];
```

to find all words in the database for that candidate list.
Then create the next array of candidates and continue.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented the batch idea, and it reduced the time from 11 seconds to just over 200 milliseconds. Works like a charm!

Comment: You sir are a true god. All I did was, as you recommended, check that indexing box, like some sort of magic it reduced it down to 20 milliseconds. I cannot begin to say how thankful I am.